# How to use numeric keypad as mouse?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Is there a way in Linux mint to use numpad as a mouse on my desktop. I have tried <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>numlock</kbd> but it did not work.

Is there a package that I must install?

Articles on the Internet are too old to be useful.

Comment: You have to look into "Assistive Technology", "Global Access" or the like in system menus. Which desktop do you use? KDE, GNOME, …?

Comment: That's the default key binding. What is your keyboard configuration? Run the program `xev`, focus its window and press Shift+NumLock: what happens? What does `xkbcomp :0 - | grep -C3 Pointer_EnableKeys` show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys
```

and then the combination.

Comment: Just because I almost left here thinking it was broken, might be worth clarifying: when you enter the above command, there is a tiny pause before returning - during which, if you press shift-numlock, it will switch you into mousekeys mode. Very odd UX!